# Spring Boot - What event fired during Oauth2 authorization success

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

I have a spring boot app that uses oauth2 for authentication. I want to add an event listener to this and perform some custom action. I am unable to figure out what event is fired during the auth success in oauth2. Is it `AuthenticationSuccessEvent`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event triggered during OAuth2 Authorization Success is `AuthorizedEvent`. This is triggered in Spring code [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/access/intercept/AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java#L247). But in order to get this event, you need set the `publishAuthorizationSuccess` to `true`. The following can be done to get this working:

The configuration changes:

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

....
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .withObjectPostProcessor(new ObjectPostProcessor<FilterSecurityInterceptor>() {
            public <O extends FilterSecurityInterceptor> O postProcess(O fsi) {
                fsi.setPublishAuthorizationSuccess(true);
                return fsi;
            }
        })
    }
....
}
```

The code listeners:

```java
@Component
@Slf4j
public class HttpSessionEventListener {
 
    @EventListener(value = {AbstractAuthorizationEvent.class})
    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationEvent event) {
        if (event instanceof AuthenticationSuccessEvent) {
            Authentication auth = ((AuthenticationSuccessEvent) event).getAuthentication();
            if (auth.getPrincipal() instanceof UserCredential) {
                log.debug("Login success with AuthenticationSuccessEvent");
            }
        } else if (event instanceof InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent) {
            Authentication auth =  ((InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent)event).getAuthentication();
            log.debug("Login success with InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent");
        } else if (event instanceof AbstractAuthenticationFailureEvent) {
            Authentication auth = ((AbstractAuthenticationFailureEvent) event).getAuthentication();
            log.debug("Login failed with AbstractAuthenticationFailureEvent");
        } else if (event instanceof AuthorizedEvent) {
            Authentication auth =  ((AuthorizedEvent)event).getAuthentication();
            log.debug("Login success with AuthorizedEvent");
        } else if (event instanceof AuthorizationFailureEvent) {
            Authentication auth =  ((AuthorizationFailureEvent)event).getAuthentication();
            log.debug("Login fail with AuthorizationFailureEvent");
        }
    }
}
```